# 提案: 表示名の文字数制限の緩和

Tags: 機能の要求

プロフィールの編集時に`表示名`を2文字にして更新しようとしたところ、下記のメッセージが表示されました。

> おっと!プロフィールの更新中に問題が発生しました。
>   表示名は 3 文字以上でなければなりません。

おそらく、非日本語圏ではあまり問題にならない制限なのかと考えていますが、日本語圏では2文字の名前も多く存在します。

そこで、`表示名`の文字数の制限を2文字以上としてはいかがでしょうか。

また、少し話が違いますが、[登録 - スタック・オーバーフロー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/signup)にて`Stack Exchange を使用して登録`をする際、`名前(あなたの公開表示名)`を2文字にして登録しようとしたところ、正常に登録確認メールが送信され受け取ることができました。
登録時に`表示名`を2文字にすることができ、更新しようとするとできないというのはシステム的にも矛盾してるのではと思います。

Comment: あら、これを一回直したと思っていましたが、検索を３文字以下だけでしたみたいです。開発者と話します。

Comment: @jmac よろしくお願いします！

Comment: I am examining this problem now.

Comment: @TimPost Thank you for your working. How about progress of work?

Comment: 表示名をひらがなに直そうとしたとき、質問文と同じメッセージが表示されて、この質問にたどり着きました。なんだかんだで 4 年経過しているようですが、いまだに文字数制限は 3 文字以上ですね。

Comment: この機能は簡単には実装できなさそうです。コメントで `@name` 形式のリプライをするとき、現状表示名が3文字以上でないと通知が飛びません。このため、この制限を2文字にするところから始めないといけません。　https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/35913/341401

Comment: Meta Stack Exchangeにおける類似投稿です: [Allow Chinese names with less than 3 characters on Chinese Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243577/341401)